# A better way to read serial device in Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have a serial device connected to USB of my Linux PC and i need constantly read data from it and process it. 
When i use `open(fd, xxx) while(1) {read(fd, xx)}` it works but i miss more than 60% of data.

Is there a better technique to have less data loss?

**Addendum**
The baud rate is 115200. we must receive at least 10 packets a second, but we get barely two.. The packet size is 22 bytes. The code is exactly the code from the second comment.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios

Comment: Yes, you need to specify more. I assume you are trying to read from a serial port. This is some code I used a few years ago: https://github.com/arhuaco/junkcode/blob/master/nitm/serial_helper.c

Comment: Well this is a Serial to USB device. Plugged in to my USB port, creates /dev/ttyACM0 device. By the way i use exactly the way from the code you linked. But the problem is - there is a huge data loss. I though there should be a trigger that turns on when any data available, so i could collect the data into array and send it to processing module.

Comment: Please describe the data loss.  What is the baud rate?  How much data are sent per second or minute? What is your actual code, how many bytes are requested per read()? How often is the read() issued?  *"Is there a better technique..."*  -- You need to provide a baseline first.

Comment: The baud rate is 115200, we must receive at least 10 packets a second, but we get barely two.. The packet size is 22 bytes. The code is exactly the code from the second comment.

Comment: That is low-quality code. It doesn't adhere to POSIX conventions: see [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237).  It's also incomplete.  You only answered half of my questions.  Where are the read() and processing code?  An average rate of 220B/s doesn't seem that difficult.